# How can I explain to my boss why I want to leave the company?

Tags: management, tech-industry, partnership

I'm currently coursing a computer science graduation at a Federal University in Brazil. I work on a startup as a trainee in web development. My boss is a really great person, but there are many reasons that I want to leave the company:

- First of all, I work exclusively with other trainee, that unfortunately, is terrible at work. He constantly loses deadlines and he always wants to decide what kind of solution we will take. We also are trying to apply the SCRUM method, but eventually he does not appears on our sprints and does not justify his absence.
- Other problem with this guy is that he always want to choose the tool that we want to use like Rails, Angular, Trello. I really don't have a problem with this, because I think if I don't know how the tool works, I will try to learn by myself, and if I fail, at least,  I hope that the person that choosed the tool have a minimal amount of knowledge about it. But is that not the case. When we start to work with Rails, by decision of this trainee, I was facing some problems and he usually didn't know how to solve then too.
- Yet I have said that my boss is a great person, he has his flaws too. As I said, my partner usually loses deadlines, so my boss wants when I finish my part, he wants I implement the tasks of the other trainee!
- Finally, I recently applied to a test on other company (that will pay me more by same amount of time) and they said that the probability of I being approve is big.

OBS: I will only leave my company if some other grant me a new job.

Comment: What do you hope to accomplish by explaining your decision to your boss? Generally, "I found an opportunity elsewhere" is as much explanation as bosses get (or expect). If they ask for more detail, you're not obligated to explain (assuming you're not violating any law or contract terms).

Comment: Exactly, what do you want to achieve by telling him this?

Comment: I just don't wanna be rude or demonstrate that I wanna leave because of my boss.

Comment: I think the point that the others are getting at here is that you don't *need* to tell your boss *why* you want to leave.  Get a new job lined and then tell him *that you're leaving.*  To paraphrase Yoda, do or do not, there is no why.

Comment: I think I got the point. Should delete this topic?

Comment: @CelsoJunior no need to (although you are free to do so), it can still get some interesting answers and further comments that could serve you (and future users) handle this situation

Comment: While you may not realise it, a lot of these problems *are* the fault of your boss. He's not providing management leadership (he should ensure the other trainee attends the scrum meetings), he's not providing technical leadership (by selecting an appropriate technology) and dumping the tasks of the other trainee on you is just incredibly bad. **A good boss would fix all those issues**.

Comment: @PhilipKendall, as I said my boss has his flaws, but I get your point and I agree with you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The best bet is always a standard 'better opportunity'.  You never know when you might want to use this boss as a reference, or even go back if things change.

Just be short in your resignation.

> I found a better opportunity that will allow me to grow in my career.  I wish you all here the best of success in your future.